# Postgres Error invalid magic number 0000

Tags: postgresql, foreman

This is the error message that I'm getting when running my postgres
    server. I've scoured the interwebs trying to  find a solution, I've
    also reinstalled `postgres` So I'm out of options but to ask it
    here.

```
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-04-06 09:03:12 EDT
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 000000010000000000000040, offset 0
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 000000010000000000000040, offset 0
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
11:51:05 postgres.1 | PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  startup process (PID 898) was terminated by signal 6: Abort trap
11:51:05 postgres.1 | LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
11:51:05 postgres.1 | exited with code 1
```

Comment: Before you do *anything* else, if this database has any data of value to you in it, read and act on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption . Make a copy of the database.

Comment: Have you ever run your database with `fsync = off` in `postgresql.conf`? Did you have a recent crash or unexpected reboot of your computer? What kind of hard drive are you using? What operating system and version? What is your PostgreSQL version? Did anything unusual happen before this happened?

Comment: I had an unexpected reboot, OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 ,  postgres is 9.4, and it didn't seem like there was anything unusual. But I have the problem fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database files are corrupted; see ["Corruption" on the PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) for advice and first steps to take.

In particular, the transaction logs that PostgreSQL is reading at startup have been corrupted. You may wish to investigate how this happened - either dodgy hardware or a disk pretending to have saved data it hasn't most likely.

If there is no data in your DB that you care about (i.e. you're just using it for development) the easiest thing to do is reset it.

Find the main postgresql database directory (probably somewhere like `/var/lib/postgresql/...`). In it you will find directories called `base`, `global`, ... `pg_xlog`. Rename that main directory as "something.OLD" or just delete everything inside it. **If you delete the contents you will permanently and unrecoverably destroy your databases and their contents** so only do that if there's nothing there that you care about.

Then run [`sudo -u postgres initdb -D /path/to/main/dir`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html) to recreate the database structure. You will then have a new empty setup and can start again. Restore databases from backup as required.

If that all sounds complicated, just find the main directory and delete it, then do a re-install. The installation should recreate the structure for you.

Comment: In suspected corruption cases please **always** link to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption and emphasis the importance of making a complete file system level copy of the DB before doing *anything* else.

Comment: Also, generally "re-install"ing will *not* re-create the databases, at least on Ubuntu or Fedora. On Ubuntu you'd have to --purge the install and delete the datadir. On Fedora you have to run `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup` anyway, so there's no point uninstalling and reinstalling.